# Is there an upasana padhathi for Vaidyanatha swarupam of Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, tantra, shaivism

I want to learn and understand the tantric aspect of the vaidyanatha swaroopam. I am pretty sure that a specific mantra, dhyana, and other angopangas of the mantra should exist for this shaivic manifestation